iPad Books not appearing in macOS Finder
When I select Books in the macOS finder, connected to my iPad, there are no books.
I have, I think, about 800 books. I see them both in the finder under iCloud Drive/Books and in the Books app, both on my iPad and on my Mac, though I haven’t counted them there. When I look at my iPad in the finder, however, there’s nothing.
All but a handful of those books were from non-bookstore sources, but even those purchased from the book store are missing:

I have the latest iPadOS and macOS, and I have checked both on my iPad and my Mac that the books are synced through iCloud. I can also verify that the total storage of about 4GB is right.
Why don’t the books appear in the Books section?

Some screenshots might make it easier to understand what you see (or don't see) where. Also, do the books show up in the Books app on the iPad? Are they downloaded to the iPad?

@nohillside I’ve added a screen shot, and mentioned that the books do appear in ht eBooks app, both on my iPad and my Mac.
